# Adding output to function PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to get my function to include the date and current user, but I keep getting an error that my function is in an invalid state. If I comment out or remove the two dbms_output... lines it works just fine. Any ideas of how to return that output? Using Oracle SQL Developer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concatenate_strings(x VARCHAR2, y VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   str1 VARCHAR2(10) := x;
   str2 VARCHAR2(10) := y;
BEGIN
   RETURN str1 || str2;
   dbms_output.put_line('The result is ' || result);
   dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' || SYSDATE || ' user: ' || 
   SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER'));
END;
/
SELECT f_concatenate_strings('Crypto','Currency') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the result Variable first, also enable the dbms_output on your SQL Developer.

This should work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concatenate_strings(x VARCHAR2, y VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   str1 VARCHAR2(10) := x;
   STR2 VARCHAR2(10) := Y;
   result VARCHAR2(250);
BEGIN
   result := str1 || str2;
   dbms_output.put_line('The result is ' || result);
   dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' || SYSDATE || ' user: ' || 
   SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER'));
RETURN result; 
END;
/
SELECT F_CONCATENATE_STRINGS('Crypto','Currency') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually eneded up having to change the name of result as it was using it as a keyword?

Comment: you can use `set serveroutput on;` before the code to enable dbms_output for that session of SQL developer

Answer (score 1):

your function has some issues.

- `result` is not declared
- `return` statement should be the last  statement in the function. it return a result and  terminates the execution of the function
- you should convert to char the sysdate

you can try  this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concatenate_strings(x VARCHAR2, y VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   --str1 VARCHAR2(10) := x;
   --str2 VARCHAR2(10) := y;
  result VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   result := x || y;

   dbms_output.put_line('The result is ' || result);
   dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' || to_char(SYSDATE,'dd.mm.yyyy') || ' user: ' || 
   SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER'));

   RETURN result; -- move to the end of the function
END;
/
SELECT f_concatenate_strings('Crypto','Currency') FROM DUAL;
```